# How to use multiple repositories in Android Studio with GitHub

Tags: android, github

I have 2 to 3 repositories in my GitHub account.First time i have done to push the project in first repository but now i want to push the project another repository from Android studio.How can i do this.Thanks .

Comment: same project to another repository?

Comment: yes same project to another repository

Comment: you can't do that. There will be a .git file inside your Android studio projects, which is linked to the original repository. So even when you try to push the code from command line  to another repository. you will get an error. so Only one repo for one project.

Comment: if i delete the previous repository which is i pushed the project from GitHub then can i use different repository

Comment: Yes. it will work and also delete .git file inside your android project directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pure git way, would be to go to the root folder of your Git repo and add another remote.

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
git remote add repo2 https://github.com/<username>/<repo2>
git push --all repo2
```

But you can manually specify another GitHub repo url with:

```
 VCS-> Import into Version control -> Share Project on GitHub.
```

Answer (score 5):

### Android Studio 4.1.1

1: Go to VCS -> Git -> Remotes -> Add your new remote.

2: VCS -> Git -> Push -> Click the underscored 'origin' (it appears as link), select your new remote and you will see the commits as well as be able to push to it.